# Merge [bad-request] into [http-status-code-400]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Please merge [bad-request](/questions/tagged/bad-request) (its wiki):

> HTTP status code 400, implying the request was not understood by the server and should not be redone without modifications.

into [http-status-code-400](/questions/tagged/http-status-code-400):

> The HTTP response status code 400 Bad Request

Which is a member of big tag family, e.g. [http-status-code-404](/questions/tagged/http-status-code-404), etc.

Comment: What is the reason for downvote?